# What is the maximum number which can be written with fewer less than sixty five symbols?

Tags: paradoxes

If you try to write down all numbers with the symbols of any alphabet using at most 65 characters, then among them there must be a maximum. Let's call it $N$. But then the number described by the phrase "maximum number which can be written with fewer less than sixty five symbols" must be greater than it, which leads to a contradiction. This phrase also describes the number and itself uses 65 symbols
while claiming that it sets this maximum number and it should be greater than $N$.
Is it paradox like Russell's paradox?

Comment: Yes, this is known as the [Berry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox). The problem is the systematic ambiguity in the phrase "can be written".

Comment: @Rahul Thank you. I'll try to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rahul says in the comments, this is known as the [Berry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox), and the problem is the ambiguity in the phrase "can be written." You can try to resolve that ambiguity by, for example, specifying a formal language such as Peano arithmetic in which to write down numbers, or specifying a programming language such as Python in which to write down programs which print out numbers.

What happens then is that

> This is a proof by contradiction that your formal language cannot express "the largest number expressible by fewer than $N$ symbols in [your formal language]."

When applied to (Turing-complete) programming languages this is a proof that, as a function of $N$, this function is not computable (in fact it grows faster than any computable function), which is related to the unsolvability of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). When applied to Peano arithmetic this is related to the [incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems).